# My estimated execution plan use TableScan instead Of Index Seek

Tags: sql-server, performance, indexing

I'm querying a table which have an index nonclustered on three columns.

Ex:

```
Create Table TableA (Col1 int, Col2 int, Col3 int, Col4 int, Col5 int)
Create nonclustered index IdxTableA ON TableA (Col1, Col2, Col3)
```

When I execute the query:

```
select * from TableA where Col1 = 1 and Col2 = 2 and Col3 = 3;
```

My estimated execution plan is a table scan operation, he doesn't use my index. My table gets a thousand lines ; I rebuilt my indexes, and my estimated execution plan is still a table scan operation.

Why the index is not use?

Comment: And what about the distribution statistics? If eg half of the rows have these values, it's cheaper to do a table scan rather than a seek, especially for such a *small* table. Rebuilding the indexes isn't going to fix what isn't broken. You can force the optimizer to use the index with a table hint but I suspect you'll find it's more expensive

Comment: Did you tried to update statistics(EXEC sp_updatestats;)?

Comment: Thousands of rows is way too small. Try adding a hundred thousand - if the value distribution is beneficial, the execution plan will use the index. Also, multi-column indices can be tricky - make sure you don't use a later column without using all the ones prior. But the core is still the same - determine if it actually means a performance impact for you, rather than just expecting the planner to do what you think is the best - most of the time, it's smarter than you are :)

Comment: EDIT : I updated statistic too, with fullscan

Comment: Thanks Luaan, i testest with hundred thousand rows, and it worked!

Answer (score 0):

The index won't be because it does not have col4 and col5.
The index is not [*covering*](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/learn-sql-server/using-covering-indexes-to-improve-query-performance/). It needs to be

```
Create nonclustered index IdxTableA ON TableA (Col1, Col2, Col3) INCLUDE (col4, col5)
```

However there are deeper problems with the table and query as given.

`SELECT *` mean all columns to if you add col6 you'd need to update the index.

Which leads to the problem that the table also has no clustered index. So you remove the avenue of "Key lookups". Key lookups are usually prevented by covering indexes, or can just be more efficient say if you only need one row.